# sending sound files as MIDI notes using AudioKit on IOS

Tags: ios, swift, midi, audiokit

i have an IOS app that use AudioKit to play AudioFiles for the sound related to the Pad. So, I want the app to support MIDI files. I want to know how to export these sound files using MIDI to play them on apps like Garage band

Comment: You're going to need to clarify what you want to do and/or make sure that you understand what MIDI is.  There is no (practical) way to convert/export a sound file into MIDI.  Please give a clear example of what you want your app to do.

Comment: there's a Pad instrument in my app that the user can use by tapping on the pad buttons , the sounds that the pad plays are sound files already added to the project files and played by audioKit , i want to add MIDI support to my app for this pad what should i do

Comment: What do you mean by 'MIDI support'? You can use your pad to send MIDI msgs to other apps/devices - but they won't play your sound files. Or you can receive MIDI msgs from other sources, which could trigger your sound files. Unless your app uses a sequencer, it doesn't make sense to talk about reading and writing MIDI files. Please give a clear example of what you want your app to do.

Comment: Your answer was clear , i just wanted to send MIDI messages to other apps and let them play my soundfiles , thanks ..

Answer (score 2):

To send MIDI:

```
// to send between app, create a virtual port:
AudioKit.midi.createVirtualOutputPort()
// you can specify which outputs you want to open, or open all by default:
AudioKit.midi.openOutput()

// to send a noteOn message:
AudioKit.midi.sendNoteOnMessage(noteNumber: aNoteNumber, velocity: aVelocity)

// to send a noteOff message:
AudioKit.midi.sendNoteOffMessage(noteNumber: aNoteNumber, velocity: 0)
```

To receive MIDI, you need to have a class which implements the `AKMIDIListener` protocol (it could even be your ViewController, but probably shouldn't be).  This class lets you implements methods such as `receivedMIDINoteOn` to handle incoming events.

```
class ClassThatImplementsMIDIListener: AKMIDIListener {
    func receivedMIDINoteOn(noteNumber: MIDINoteNumber,
                            velocity: MIDIVelocity,
                            channel: MIDIChannel) {
        // handle the MIDI event in your app, e.g., trigger you sound file
    }
}
```

Setting it up is easy:

```
// if you want to receive midi from other apps, create a virtual in
AudioKit.midi.createVirtualInputPort()

// you can specify which inputs you want to open, or open them all by default
AudioKit.midi.openInput()

// add your listener
AudioKit.midi.addListener(classImplementingMIDIListener)
```